# Python MySQL connection randomly lost

Tags: python, connection, mysql-python

I have the following problem:

I am using Python with MySQLdb and a SSDictCursor to iterate over a pretty large database (250M lines). Because I am unable to load everything into RAM, I am using the streaming API. On the MySQL server, the max_allowed_packet size is already set to 512M.

I ran my script from different computers (also from the server machine itself) and it keeps crashing at random times after a random number of processed rows with the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
Exception _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') in <bound method SSDictCursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor object at 0x7fa360e1a690>> ignored
```

I'm not using threads or anything fancy. I'm totally at a loss why this happens. Has anyone any idea how to solve this otherwise?

EDIT: Some sample code for you.

```
mysql = MySQLdb.connect("host", "user", "pass", "db")

cursor = mysql.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor)
cursor.execute("select stuff from database order by date asc")
for row in cursor:
     # just repacking all the information in the cursor row into some dict

cursor.close()
```

Hopefully, that piece of code helped you. In the for loop, I'm only doing some lookups in a local defaultdict.

Somewhere around 80M entries (or maybe also 40M or whatever), my program stops because of the above mentioned error. The data must be transferred in sequential order. Also, because of the random number of processed lines, I'm pretty sure that it's not because of some faulty line in the database. On the server itself, there is only the server instance running, no other programs, as far as I checked.

Comment: There could be millions of reasons, we need to see your code. It might be the mysql cursor it might be the server, there are infinite reasons.

Comment: I have had the same problem with `SSDictCursor` but never found a solution, except to re-open the connection as needed, or switch to buffered cursors and write my longer queries in chunks.

Comment: Use try/except to trap the error and reopen the connection and continue on.

Comment: I finally dumped the contents of the MySQL database into a text file and used pandas. This is not a real solution for the mentioned problem, but a good and fast workaround.